# Visual Studio Shortcut keys and Intellisense Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a strange issue with regards to my visual studio 2008 when debugging.

It seems to be only on one project, a web site that im currently developing, for some reason when debugging. None of the basic short cut keys work like F10/F11 to step through the code. Even when hovering over something with the mouse which usually shows the value, doesnt work properly, will do it the first time, then freeze.

I have tried comparing web.config files with projects that debug properly, even tried recreating the project, tried resetting the keyboard mappings, and im just about out of ideas now, the only thing i havent done is repair the visual studio, but my conclusion is, if it was visual studio it would be doing it for all projects.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Regards
Chris

Note: I can step through the code with the mouse (clicking on the icons) however this is very slow, takes a noticable amount of time to move from one line to the other.

EDIT: After more trial and errors, I had it work once, but i dont know how i made it work, all i did was an IISReset, then it worked once, was able to debug like normal, however when i tried to debug again, went back to as described above, tried another IISReset but didnt work this time.

Comment: 1. Have you tried retarting Visual Studio?
 2. What plug-ins have you installed that may be affecting the shortcuts?
 3. Are you working within a virtual machine environment?

Comment: I have tried restarting Visual Studio, I have even attempted a repeair, but didnt work. I havent installed any additional plugins, and its normal working environment, on laptop.

Comment: Try starting visual studio in safe mode and see if the shortcuts work, safemode should olnly allow the default VS exe to run without any plugins http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting your Visual Studio 
Reset Settings
The command "devenv /resetsettings" will restore Visual Studio back to its original factory state.

If not that try a clear re-install. An other possible thingie could be your memories not sure though. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much, however unfortunately this wasnt successful. The enviroment did reset all the settings, but didnt cure my debugging problem. It just seems to be affecting this one project.

Comment: Sorry for late update, but the only way around this I found, was doing a clear install of Visual Studio and the readding all my projects one by one.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and it turned out the "F Lock" function lock key on my keyboard had been depressed, preventing any of the F1-F12 keys from working.  You can verify that this is your problem by running the on-screen keyboard that comes with Windows and seeing if the shortcuts work when you press the function keys using that keyboard.  If that is the case, look for some sort of F-lock functionality on your keyboard.

Comment: Indeed. The BIOS settings can also decide what is the default state.

Comment: I had this issue.  On my keyboard, the above mentioned "F Lock" key is labelled as "F Mode" and it is located next to the F12 key, after a short gap.  Debugger was taking commands from the keyboard alright till a reboot at which point it booted to some state where the debugger wouldn't respond to the keyboard.  I had to press the "F Mode" key once to restore keyboard inputs to the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

Now a days new generation laptops/computers are coming with a "Fn" key on the keyboard in the bottom line. Simply pressing the "F12" or "F11" keys for "STEP INTO" or "STEP OVER" in VISUAL STUDIO will no longer work on those laptops/computers. You have to press and hold the "Fn" key and then press your desired key as "F12" or "F11"

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and I tried everything including: restarting computer, devenv.exe /resetsettings, Tools > Import/Export Settings > Reset All, devenv.exe /safemode, turning of visual styling in Windows, and checking keyboard settings in Windows. 
None of these works. I then **deleted the .suo file associated to my solution** and *that* fixed it!
I have no idea *why* though.

Answer (score 1):

I had all my function keys disabled in Visual Studio (v19, v22) and had tried several hours looking for a solution. Suddenly no function key was acting in Visual Studio(F1-F12), exept only function keys that had some windows functions (e.g. startup menu etc.).
And, the solution was very simple, idiotic simple. I had accidentally turned the function keys off.

You may have a function lock turned off; mine was Fn+Esc. Tuggle it to turn it on again.